# Get Row Value based on count

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet document and I am trying to list next person's turn.  Essentially a user will enter a number and by the count of total numbers entered, the next person is shown.

Normally if I wanted to list a value from another cell I would type

```
=B2
```

However I need my number 2 to be dynamic, so something like:

```
=BCOUNTA(A2:A900)
```

Of course the above doesn't work, how do I get it to work?

EDIT: Found an answer with [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?visit_id=1-636127660058032621-2495895080&rd=1%22INDEX%22) have optional rows&columns offset.